# unexpected behavior when importing packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I got an unexpected importing behavior in python, which I don't understand. Hopefully you can help me clarify this behavior. Assuming following project structure:

```
.
└── pkgimp
    ├── __init__.py
    └── testing
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── mod_a.py
        └── mod_b.py
```

with following source code:

**pkgimg/__init__.py**:

```
import pkgimg.testing
```

**pkgimg/testing/__init__.py**:

```
from mod_a import a
from mod_b import b # <- no import of c
```

**pkgimg/testing/mod_a.py**:

```
a = 123
```

**pkgimg/testing/mod_b.py**:

```
b = "foo"
c = "bar" # <- not imported
```

when I'm importing the package with `import pkgimp` and printing the loaded modules with `dir(pkgimp.testing)` I see the modules `mod_a` and `mod_b` which i didn't import?

Here is what I get:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'a', 'b', 'mod_a', 'mod_b']
```

I was assuming that only `a` and `b` will be import and neither `mod_a` nor `mod_b`

Additionally, I have access to `c` which never has been imported anywhere.

```
>>> pkgimp.testing.mod_b.c
'bar'
```

I know, that everything in the modules will be evaluated if they will be imported. However, I thought, using `from M import x` will give me the reference only to `x` not the whole module!?

For example when I run following code:

```
>>> from pkgimp.testing.mod_b import b
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'b']
```

Python only imports b not, the module `mod_b`. This is what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules in packages, once imported, are always added as attributes of the package.

So when importing `pkgimp.testing.mod_b` **from any other module**, a `mod_b` name is added to `pkgimp.testing`. This is normal behaviour.

In your last example, you imported a specific name from a module into your local namespace. If you were to inspect the `mod_b` module through `sys.modules['pkgimp.testing.mod_b']` you'll find that `c` is still defined on that object; the whole module is loaded into memory and a reference to `b` is added to your local namespace.

In that case too, `sys.modules['pkgimp.testing']` will have a `mod_b` attribute, which is a reference to the `pkgimp.testing.mod_b` module object.

Comment: ok, this clarifies anything. thanks and also for the `sys.modules` hint, I wasn't aware of this. as I said, I know, that the module will be completely evaluated and the code be loaded into the memory, but I didn't know, that it will be automatically added to the attributes of the package.